# How to label and change the scale of Seaborn kdeplot's axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


fig = sns.kdeplot(treze, shade=True, color=c1,cut =0, clip=(0,2000))
fig = sns.kdeplot(cjjardim, shade=True, color=c2,cut =0, clip=(0,2000))

fig.figure.suptitle("Plot", fontsize = 24)

plt.xlabel('Purchase amount', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Distribution', fontsize=16)
```

, which results in the following plot:

[image]

I want to do two things:

1) Change the scale of the y-axis by multiplying its values by 10000 and, if it's possible, add a % sign to the numbers. In other words, I want the y-axis values shown in the above plot to be 0%, 5%, 10%, 15%, 20%, 25%, and 30%.

2) Add more values to the x-axis. I'm particularly interested in showing the data in intervals of 200. In other words, I want the x-axis values shown in the plot to be 0, 200, 400, 600,... and so on.

Comment: Do you just want a histogram of the frequencies? I mean, it makes little sense to use a density estimation and then multiply by a constant and discretize it.

Comment: Maybe? I think a histogram could be an alternative to show the differences between those distributions but I think a kernel density plot is more effective for my purpose.

Comment: This is just a matplotlib axes so you would change the axes labels the same way you would with a normal matplotlib plot. However, you seem a bit confused about what the y axis represents. Why do you want to multiply it by 10000 and add a percentage? That won't be accurate.

Comment: @iatowks nice plot. How did you get the legends to show? I am using kdeplot and I set the legend keyword to True but am unable to show the legend.

Comment: what does the y-axis represent in the kde plot ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1) what you are looking for is most probably some combination of get_yticks() and set_yticks:

```
plt.yticks(fig.get_yticks(), fig.get_yticks() * 100)
plt.ylabel('Distribution [%]', fontsize=16)
```

Note: as mwaskom is commenting times 10000 and a % sign is mathematically incorrect.

2) you can specify where you want your ticks via the xticks function. Then you have more ticks and data get easier to read. You do not get more data that way.

```
plt.xticks([0, 200, 400, 600])
plt.xlabel('Purchase amount', fontsize=18)
```

Note: if you wanted to limit the view to your specified x-values you might even have a glimpse at plt.xlim() and reduce the figure to the interesting range.